# Setting UnityEvents from the editor and making them call the right argument

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working with UnityEvents as stated [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/UnityEvents.html). There it is written

> When configuring a UnityEvent in the Inspector there are two types of
> function calls that are supported:
>
> Static. Static calls are preconfigured calls, with preconfigured
> values that are set in the UI. This means that when the callback is
> invoked, the target function is invoked with the argument that has
> been entered into the UI.
>
> Dynamic. Dynamic calls are invoked using an
> argument that is sent from code, and this is bound to the type of
> UnityEvent that is being invoked. The UI filters the callbacks and
> only shows the dynamic calls that are valid for the UnityEvent.

so I get a UnityEvent with an argument as in

```
 public class UnityEventFloat : UnityEvent<float>
    {
    }
public UnityEventFloat OnUpdateEvent;
```

This appears in the inspector as

[image: A callback entered to a UnityEvent]

As you can see I have added a callback function `setWaitTime` to the UnityEvent.
The function has this shape   `public void setWaitTime(float t)`

After that the UnityEvent is going to be invoked in code as

```
OnUpdateEvent.Invoke(aValue);
```

Trying all this, it is not working well since the function when invoked is using as argument 0 (as in the Inspector)
What I want is that it calls the function with the argument `aValue` (which is an internal variable in code)

How can I do this? I guess I am not quite understanding the quote above from the documentation. My situation is like the "Static" one, and I require it works like the "Dynamic"

---

EDIT2:

I got to solve the problem, so I am going to write it in an answer

---

EDIT:(Old)
I tried the proposed answer and I got this
[image]
I don't know how this can solve the problem (notice that now the parameter is the script. But this is inside the same script (SliderGestureControl))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally got to make it work. Apparently I was making a mistake when selecting the function from the drop down list. I selected the function under the "Static" label but I should have selected the same function but under the "Dynamic" label that was at the top of the list (and I didn't see).

With that the function `setWaitTime` does not have any parameter in the inspector (so it uses dynamically what is given to it by the UnityEvent.